# how to get scope for "this" in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

I have the following class:

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {

        constructor() {
            this.bindEvents();
        }

        bindEvents() {
            var self = this;
            $("#save-button").off("click")
                .click(() => {
                    self.classFunction();
                });
        };

        classFunction(){
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the self variable now to contain a reference to the class. (The compile even tells me it does!)

However, when the js is loaded on the client it cannot find the function, bevause self points to the window object instead of the class.

How can I implement this so that I have a reference to my class?

generated js:

```
        ClassName.prototype.bindEvents= function () {
            var self = this;
            $("#save-button").off("click")
                .click(function () {
                self.classFunction();
            });
        };
```

Comment: Since you use an arrow function, `this` should be preserved anyway. so `()=> this.classFunction()` should work no need for `self`. How are you invoking `bindEvents` is is as in the sample code in the constructor or on some other event ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, I am calling bindEvents in the constructor, as shown in my example. When I try your solution, it is the same result. "this" points to the window instead of the class. I added the generated js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrow function will solve your problem.

```
const bindEvents = () => {
 // your code
}
```

ES6 does not autobind 'this' to the class syntax, while inside a normal function.

Using arrow function will refer 'this' to class.

Comment: Not that this should be necessary here…

Comment: this worked for me and it was necessary. Perhaps due to ES5 still being in use? But without the arrow, the compiler produced the wrong scoping in js